# Not able to build Visual Studio Database Project targeting Azure SQL Database when using AT TIME ZONE

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

We have a [Visual Studio Database Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-data-tools/hh272702(v=vs.103)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) that we are trying to move to Azure SQL Database. Some of our views use [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) which is supported in Azure SQL Database, but when I switch the database Target Platform to Microsoft Azure SQL Database in the project properties, it fails to build with error:

> Error: SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near TIME.

[image: Database Project Properties]

I have connected directly to the database in Azure and I can use `AT TIME ZONE`, but I cannot create or publish a `DACPAC` file from my project.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386611/unable-to-build-sql-server-project-because-of-at-time-zone) suggests switching the target to SQL Server 2016, but then you cannot deploy the `DACPAC` to Azure. It will give the error

> A project which specifies SQL Server 2016 as the target platform cannot be published to Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.

when publishing from Visual Studio or the command line with `sqlpackage.exe`. (Same with all targets).

This seems like a long-standing bug in Visual Studio Data Tools so others must have run into it. Does anyone have a workaround or suggestions?

Comment: Hi Rob. Does this help? https://medium.com/modern-stack/deploy-a-sql-dacpac-to-azure-using-vsts-d24fb473302f

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo, unfortunately, that doesn't help. The fix in the post is to pass in a property that 'retargets' the build to Azure. Doing so causes the AT TIME ZONE error. The post is basically doing what I do in the image above, but using a property at compile time.

Comment: Would you consider updating your DacFx. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x86 and here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40735. Then do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315074/unable-to-publish-dacpac-to-azure-sql-database-using-sqlpackage-exe/50321062#50321062  ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @AlbertoMorillo but I'd already updated SQL Package. The issue isn't with publishing, but with building the project when it targets SQL Azure.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the answer to this through another channel. This is a bug in Visual Studio 16.4 and the current preview of 16.5.

The Visual Studio 16.4 release removed support for Microsoft Azure SQL Database V11. In doing so, they removed the Project target for **Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12**, making the **Microsoft Azure SQL Database** the only option. The intention was for this new option to switch to targeting V12, but there is a bug and it still targets V11.

[image: Option Removed in 16.4]

Until this is fixed in a future update of Visual Studio, the workaround is to manually edit the **SQLPROJ** file and change the line;

```xml
<DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureDatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
```

Adding in **V12** to make it;

```xml
<DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
```

Save and reopen the solution. It now compiles and I can deploy to Azure.

Comment: Rob on the first article I shared the author did the same https://medium.com/modern-stack/deploy-a-sql-dacpac-to-azure-using-vsts-d24fb473302f

Comment: You can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo in the article, the author changed the build target at compile time with a property, I was trying to change it in Visual Studio, but the V12 option has been removed. I had assumed that because it had been removed, it was no longer a valid compile target which was incorrect.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you

Comment: If you don't see V12 option , only `Microsoft Azure SQL Database` option , select it , and check SQLPROJ file , if that is `<DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>` , then it will be fine .

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo The solution works unless you don't copy the text in the code under "Here is the MSBuild Argument for each copy\paste;".They made a mistake and wrote a wrong variable. That confused me a little.

Comment: This also works in VS2022 with the following line, which throws the same error. `<DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql130DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>`

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Has anyone found a solution yet?

Answer (score 7):

This is the answer just to the second part of the question.

I had the same error while publishing `.dacpac` from free azure sql database to the one in basic plan.

> A project which specifies SQL Server 2016 as the target platform cannot be published to Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.

I figured that out by checking `Allow incompatible platform` in `Advance` setting of `Publish Data-tier Application`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, i used this argument in my CD and it works great. Don't need to update sqlproj file.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me is simply going to the projects properties section and changing from SQL Server 2022 to SQL Server 2019.

[image]

Hope this helps.