# Azure SQL database creation issue from dacpac

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I am trying to create new SQL Azure database using dacpac file created from local SQL server database using SSDT .

[image: Export Database as dacpac]

I am getting error as

**Publish failed.An error occured during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue. A project which specifies SQL Server 2017 as the target platform cannot be published to Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.**

But did not get any option to choose while doing Extract Data-tier Application to generate dacpac.

Below is error while creating Azure SQL database :

[image: Publish Data-Tier Application Failed]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this workaround, you can go into the json file for the project and manually target V12. Edit the sqlproj file.

```
<DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
```

Comment: can you elaborate on how to add target v12. I have exported dacpac using extract data-tier application. please check updated screenshot in question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59688412/not-able-to-build-visual-studio-database-project-targeting-azure-sql-database-wh

Comment: I don't have database project for this. I have exacted by connecting to sql server in local.